# Using VBA to scrape data

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

I am trying to pull the price data for **Tropical Veggie** ($5) from the code below using VBA

```
h2 class="ng-binding" Meat Lovers/h2
h3 class="ng-biding" ng-show="canShowPrice"$9.00/h3
h2 class="ng-binding"Tropical Veggie/h2
h3 class="ng-biding" ng-show="canShowPrice"$5.00/h3
```

Here is my code

```
Dim TropicalVeggie As String
TropicalVeggie = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("ng-binding")(0).innerText
```

I think part of the problem is that there are multiple class names with "ng-binding". But I have no idea

Comment: Is it returning "Meat Lovers"? That seems to be what the code is supposed to do using the `(0).innerText`.

Comment: As you say, the class ng-binding has multiple occurances. You need to search all occurances of this class and find the innerText containing "Tropical Veggie". It's a simple loop